# PowerShell XAML WPF Window obtaining values

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

Nice and easy one to explain, but struggling to find an answer.

In the below code, a nice pretty box opens up, and when you select a row, a sub row appears with further data.
What I'm trying to do is get access to the sub row headers.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'presentationframework' )

[xml]$XAML = @'


    <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="Global Core Desktop Toolbox" Height="550" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
        <Grid>

            <Grid Background="#FF0A2F64">
                <DataGrid Name="Datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Height="250" Width="675" Margin="40,125,0,0" Visibility="Visible" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Domain" Binding="{Binding Domain}" Width="Auto" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Live PCs" Binding="{Binding LiveMachines}" Width="Auto"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DR" Binding="{Binding DR}" Width="40"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel Background="GhostWhite">
                                <Grid Margin="0,10">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Domain: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Domain}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

                                    <TextBlock Text="Disabled Machines: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="2" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SamAccountDisabled}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />

                                    <TextBlock Text="Servers: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="3" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Servers}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                </DataGrid>


            </Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>

'@

#Read XAML
$READER  = ( New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML ) 
Try {
    $FORM    = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $READER ) 
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader."
    Sleep 4 
}

$XAML.SelectNodes( "//*[@Name]" ) | %{ Set-Variable -Name ( $_.Name ) -Value 
$FORM.FindName( $_.Name ) }


 $datagrid.AddChild( [pscustomobject]@{ 
            Domain       = "happytimes.local"
            LiveMachines = 6
            DR           = 1
            Servers      = 2
            SamAccountDisabled = 3
        } )

$form.ShowDialog()
```

So if i do `$datagrid.Columns.header` , I have access to "Domain", "Total Live PCs" and "DR" - which i use in a foreach loop. It's the "Domain", "Disabled Machines" and "Servers" I'm trying to get to. `$datagrid.items` gives me everything with the numbers, but I can't break it down further.

Am i missing something? Any ideas how I get to the variable?

Thanks

Comment: XAML is WPF not WinForms.

Comment: What do you get if you pipe `$datagrid` to `Get-Member`? Can you check other properties?